# Is there a way to embed the DocuSign prepare or send envelope control panel in my webpage?

Tags: docusignapi

I am working on a DocuSign integration and want to allow the sender of the envelope to view the control panel to drag and drop signature tabs onto the document.

I already have a successful implementation that sends an embedded envelope to the signers. However, for this specific requirement, I do not know a) the X/Y coordinates of the signing tabs, or b) any anchor string for the signature tabs.

I have looked at the DocuSign api and I cannot see a way outside of java, which isn't really what im going for.

I am hoping to use this in an iframe, similar to how the embedded signing panel is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the [EnvelopeViews::CreateSenderView](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createSender) method is what you're looking for.

You can create a draft, then do the CreateSenderView call to request a url to a session of the DocuSign tagging screen. Since you're wanting to go straight to the tagger, you can leave the `send=1` parameter as-is. If you wanted the URL to go to the Documents/Recipients screen instead of the tagger, you could change the url you recive from DocuSign to end with `send=0` instead.

Do heed the Information Security warning on that API call: The Sender View URL will provide full access to the Web Console for whoever the authenticated user is. This is not a concern if you have one membership per user, but if you are using a shared membership everyone will have access to all envelopes on that membership.

Comment: So it looks like the request I was looking for is the CreateEditView. That provides me with the correct view of the envelope where I can drag in the signature tabs, however it doesn't seem to take me back to my redirect URL after I've hit "Send". Instead it takes me back to the DocuSign dashboard. Is there any way to change that behavior?